# Помогите реализовать алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм, java

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, помогите реализовать алгоритм.

Даны целые числа от `N_MIN` до `N_MAX`. Необходимо вычислить все возможные последовательности этих чисел, при условии, что одно число не должно повторяться в последовательности дважды. Длина последовательности варьируется от `CH_MIN` до `CH_MAX`.

Поработав своим скудным количеством извилин, я пришёл к выводу, что задача решается с помощью циклов. Моя недоделанная реализация:

```
        //Сначала будем создавать последовательности с размером n,
        //потом n+1 и так далее, пока не достигнем максимкльного размера
        for (; CH_MIN < CH_MAX; CH_MIN++)
        {
            //С каждой итерацией данного цикла будем добавлять число
            //к последовательности, пока её размер не достигнет CH_MIN
            for (int CH_CUR = 0; CH_CUR < CH_MIN; CH_CUR++)
            {
                String CHAIN = "";
                //Выбираем первое число последовательности (N_MIN)
                for (int i = N_MIN; i < N_MAX; i++)
                {
                    CHAIN += (i + "");
                    //Далее надо выбрать остальные числа последовательности,
                    //но я не знаю, как это сделать.
                }
            }
        }
```

Была идея делать массив с числами от `N_MIN` до `N_MAX`, при каждом добавлении числа к последовательности убирать добавленное число из массива, чтобы в нём остались допустимые для добавления числа (это я так пытаюсь избежать повторения чисел). Однако я так запутался, что не смог реализовать ни идею с массивом, ни с циклами.

Comment: Такие вопросы отвлекают от работы! :)

Для начала можно попробовать переоборудовать генератор словаря паролей, где исходная строка "012..9abc..z" как бы задает N-ную систему счисления (N — длина исходной строки).

Задаем «нуль»: `0`, потом `1`, и так до `z` (это «N-ое число», которое в 10-ной СС было бы равно 10 — последнее из ряда). Следующее будет `00`, за ним — `01`, `02` и так далее до `zz` — до максимального двухразрядного числа N-ой системы счисления. Да, нужно при всем не забывать, что цифры не должны повторяться.

Но с 10-ми числами, очевидно, можно найти более оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант, правда на JS ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1Lq18be/4/); исправлена процедура определения длины всей последовательности):

```
function generateSequence(min, max)
    {
    var alphabet = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++)
        alphabet.push(i);

    var res = [];
    var cur = null;
    var n = max-min + 1;
    var size = n;

    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
        size += Math.pow(n, i + 1);

    function getNext(seq)
        {
        if (!seq)
            return [alphabet[0]];

        var index = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i <= seq.length; i++)
            {
            if (i == seq.length + 1)
                {
                seq[i] = alphabet[0];
                break;
                }

            index = alphabet.indexOf(seq[i]) + 1;
            if (index < alphabet.length)
                {
                seq[i] = alphabet[index];
                break;
                }
            else
                seq[i] = alphabet[0];
            }

        return seq;
        }

    var temp;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
        cur = getNext(cur);
        temp = ',' + cur.join(',') + ',';
        if (!temp.match(/,([^,]+),\1|,([^,]+),(?=.*,\2,)/))
            res.push(cur.join('-').split('-').reverse().join('-'));
        }

    return res;
    }
```

Comment: @Bars, спасибо! Так как мне надо будет портировать этот код на Java, то задам ещё один вопрос:

Что значит `if (!seq)`? Я просто в JS не очень силён, просто видно, что тут вы работаете с этой переменной как с `Boolean`, а потом как с `Array`.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, [преобразование-к-логическому-типу][1]


  [1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#преобразование-к-логическому-типу

Comment: @woesss, однако классная в JS проверка на null :D И последний вопрос: как я понял, в JavaScript массивы "резиновые", то есть их размер автоматически изменяется. Но в Javа строки

    if (i == seq.length + 1)
    {
        seq[i] = alphabet[0];
        break;
    }

Выкинут `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Можно ли как нибудь это обойти?

Comment: Зато в Java есть `ArrayList`, к примеру. Я понимаю, что производительность несколько упадет. `seq` можно представлять строкой с разделителем — мне кажется, что так будет полегче, чем заменять на `ArrayList`. Размер `res` рассчитывается заранее:


    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
        size += Math.pow(n, i + 1);

`size` будет несколько больше, чем на самом деле нужно, но, как водится — лучше перебдеть. Я не смог вывести простую формулу для подсчета кол-ва элементов с учетом того, что дублирующиеся «знаки» внутри самих элементов не должны повторяться.

Answer (score 2):

1) Первоначальный стэк чисел.
 2) 2 последовательно у нас уже есть готовые, первая и реверсная.

Дальше можно прикинуть кол-во вариантов, это будет кол-во позиций (длина стэка) в степени кол-во уникальных чисел.

Дальше, думаю, можно создать матрицу, в которой ряд - это уникальная последовательность, остается придумать, как ее заполнять. =)

3) Пока что придумал, надо сдвигать сначала вправо по кругу на одно позицию, тогда получим все варианты первой последовательности, но надо еще варианты с вертикальным сдвигом.